# Why does the GWT generator does not save my file to disk when I create a new one with context.tryCreateResource?

Tags: java, gwt

I tried to generate a java file and a ui.xml file containing many buttons with the GWT deferred binding generator.

My java file gets generated and written to my -gen location well. But the **corresponding ui.xml file is not in my -gen folder**, and I do not know why.

my function crating the ui.xml file looks like:

```
public String generate(TreeLogger logger, GeneratorContext context,
      String typeName) throws UnableToCompleteException {

    try {
      SourceWriter sw = getSourceWriter(typeName, context, logger);
      assert(sw != null);
      // after the file got created, I write the class content
      /* ... */ UiBinder Java code

      createUiXMLFile(typeName, context, logger);

      sw.commit(logger); 
      // after this command the java class file is written is to -gen folder
      System.out.println("class '" + typeName +  "Generated' was created succesfully");
      return typeName + "Generated";
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
}


public void createUiXMLFile(String typeName, GeneratorContext context, 
        TreeLogger logger) throws Exception {

    // gets the type given by the String typeName
    JClassType classType = context.getTypeOracle().getType(typeName);
    // gets the package in which the new class should get created
    String packageName = classType.getPackage().getName();
    // gets the name of the class without the package name
    String simpleName = classType.getSimpleSourceName();
    simpleName = simpleName + "Generated";
    // for us to see what classes were generated by this generator

    OutputStream os = context.tryCreateResource(logger, 
          packageName.replace(".", "/")+"/"+simpleName+".ui.xml");
    // it does also not work if I just use
    // context.tryCreateResource(logger, simpleName+".ui.xml");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baus = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // just for testing, that I wrote the XML code into the PrintWriter
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(baus);

    pw.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    /* the UiBinder XML code ... */
    pw.println("</ui:UiBinder>");
    pw.flush();

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:\\...\\view\\UnicodeCharViewGenerated.ui.xml");
    fout.write(baus.toByteArray());
    fout.close();

    os.write(baus.toByteArray());
    context.commitResource(logger, os);
    // even after doing the commit the file is not written to the -gen location
}
```

I guess that I forgot to call any function to add the new file to the Oracle; but I do not know what method I should call.

If I use the FileOutputStream and write the ui.xml file direct into my Eclipse workspace, than it works. But if I comment this line out, than the compiler cannot find the .ui.xml file and
deferred binding failed.

Comment: Isn't `tryCreateResource` for outputting _public_ artifacts?

Comment: Yes you are right, the file is in the WebContent folder.

Do you know the command to write the ui.xml file into the source -gen folder?

I used the command *ClassSourceFileComposerFactory* before, but I do not want to create a class, just the xml file.

Comment: Quickly looked at the `ImplicitCssResource` from UiBinder, which generates a CSS file from the `<ui:style>` elements, it seems to create a temp file and use a special value in the generated `@Source` annotation. Haven't dug how that value is handled later on. You might be able to do the same, generating a `@UiTemplate` annotation. Will post an answer once I find out how it all works.

Comment: I will persue the approach and will debug the `ImplicitCssResource` class. Because until your comment I resigned after taking a look at the `StandardGeneratorContext` class 
 and seeing the line `File srcFile = new File(dir, simpleTypeName + ".java");`, showing that you can only create Java files.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `Resources` (`ClientBundle`) has a hook/hack to allow other modules to _publish_ files as resources to be used at a later stage of generation. Have you tried the `File.createTempFile` + `@UiTemplate` approach? Or, as big ugly hack, you could possibly generate XML into a `.java` file _via_ the `StandardGeneratorContext`

Comment: The Approach with `@UiTemplate` and writing the content into a .java file does not work. You get the following error message _14:04:11.997 [ERROR] Template file name must end with .ui.xml_ . If create a `File` with `File.createTempFile`, than I cannot set the absolute paht to the `@UiTemplate` Annotation. The easiest way is probably changing code in the `StandardGeneratorContext` to ommit the + ".java", if the file has a suffix like ".xml". The `ImplicitCssResource`uses `ResourceGeneratorUtil.addNamedFile(getBodyFileName(), generatedFile);` to generate its CSS file in the public Folder.

Comment: I'd say: short-term: use reflection to be able to generate a `.ui.xml` file; long-term: file a bug on GWT to be able to generate non-Java files to the _classpath_ (and update UiBinder to use it for the implicit `CssResource`), and to speed it up don't hesitate to send a patch for review.

Comment: The solution isn't so easy as I thought. You can create the *.ui.xml file, but the problem is that you have to add the generated file to the `resourceOracle`, in order that the `UiBinderGenerator` class can find it. But I do not know how to add it, because `getResourcesOracle().getResourceMap().put(gcup.getSourceMapPath(), new FileResource(new DirectoryClassPathEntry(new File(dirPath)), sourcePath, new File(fileLocation)));` does not work since the map is immutable. This means you can create the ui.xml file, but the file is not found by the other compiler classes.

Comment: So, only alternative is to generate only Java. After all, UiBinder generates code that you could write yourself in the end, so your generator could generate that code directly.

Comment: Yes, that is the thing I did before. I used `StringBuilder` and created a large HTML string. The not so nice thing, is to register the `Button` handlers. I used `DOM.getChildrenCount()` and iterated recursively over all the generated HTML, and then I added the `EventListener` to the DOM objects, and I had to sink the DOM events. My hope was, that it would work with `UiBinder`, so the compiler does the ugly handler registration, and I can use the normal `ClickHandler` and have not to deal with HTML DOM and not have to invoke the `ClickEvent` in the `onBrowserEvent` manually.

Comment: Why not generating the same kind of code that UiBinder would generate?

Answer (score -2):

As per my knowledge through java script(gwt) we can't write content (byte array) into drives of the system.